# std::begin and std::end iterators in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, iterator, stdarray

I am trying to compile nghttp2,opensource, in windows. I already compiled successfully the same in Linux.

I am facing compilation error from the following piece of code.
*

```
template <size_t N> struct Memchunk {
public:
  Memchunk(Memchunk *next_chunk)
      : pos(std::begin(buf)), last(pos), knext(next_chunk), next(nullptr) {}
  size_t len() const { return last - pos; }
  size_t left() const { return std::end(buf) - (const size_t) last; }
  void reset() { pos = last = std::begin(buf); }
  std::array<uint8_t, N> buf;
  uint8_t *pos, *last;
  Memchunk *knext;
  Memchunk *next;
  static const size_t size = N;
};
```

*

I am getting the following error.

```
error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from'std::_Array_const_iterator<_Ty,16384>' to 'std::size_t'
```

I didn't face the aforementioned error in Linux. Am I missing something in specific to Visual Studio?

Comment: look like very bad c++ code.

Comment: gcc don't like it either. http://ideone.com/SJNXbJ. What compiler accepts this? The error makes sense to me.

Comment: Why not `std::array<uint8_t, N>::iterator pos, last;`? I don't get it.

Comment: @SJ_3  Nothing guarantees that an iterator of the class std::array can be converted to the type std::array<T, N>::pointer.

Comment: Is this code from an existing software project? Or did you write it? If you wrote it then you need to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and tell us what problem code like this is supposed to solve. If it's code from an existing project my recommendation is that you simply throw this badly coded program away and find something better that solves your problem.

Comment: @SJ_3  Take into account that neither knext nor next is used inside the class. So it looks like the design of the class is wrong or incomplete.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The piece of code I pasted above is from existing opensource project.  I wrote a small program related to the actual problem which compiles in Linux but not in Visual studio.                                                          `#include <array>
using namespace std;

int foo(std::array<unsigned int, 10> &a)
{
      unsigned int *b = a.begin();
      return a.end() - b;
}
int main(void) {
      std::array<unsigned int, 10> a={1,2,3,4};
      foo(a);
}` I am facing the same error.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude link: http://ideone.com/a23Lzq

Comment: The problem is that the programmer of the original source apparently didn't read the specification (or a reference). Because while a pointer can sometimes be *used* as an iterator, pointers and iterator are not the same thing. The GCC `std::array` iterator and the MSVC++ `std::array` iterator are implemented differently, leading to this mismatch of types. In short, an iterator is not a pointer, but a pointer can be an iterator. The code uses a non-portable implementation-specific detail as a kind of optimization (I guess) which then fails on other platforms and implementations.

Answer (score 0):

the problem might stem from `std::begin()` returning an pointer
on linux, and a proper iterator in windows. This plus some bugs.

If you add `begin` and `end` as convenience functions to the class, like this:

```
template <size_t N> struct Memchunk {
    uint8_t* begin() { return buf.data(); }
    uint8_t* end() { return buf.data()+N; }
    const uint8_t* begin() const { return buf.data(); }
    const uint8_t* end() const { return buf.data()+N; }
    // rest not shown
};
```

Then `left()` can be implemented like:

```
    size_t left() const { return end() - last; }
```

Possibly with a cast to silence a warning

The `pos` member can now be initialized with `begin()` in the member initialization list

Comment: I wrote a small program, related to the actual problem, which compiles in Linux but not in Visual studio. ` #include <array>
using namespace std;
int foo(std::array<unsigned int, 10> &a)
{
unsigned int *b = a.begin();
return a.end() - b;
}
int main(void) {
std::array<unsigned int, 10> a={1,2,3,4};
foo(a);
}`  I am getting the following error in Visual studio   `
Error C2678 binary '-': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::_Array_iterator<_Ty,10>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
` Ideone link [link](http://ideone.com/a23Lzq)

Answer (score 0):

This is Visual Studio inserting extra type/debug information. This sometimes makes it less than compatible with std algorithms. That said, it's the price you pay for some pretty awesome array over/under run detection, and so forgivable.
Fortunately the work-around is easy...

Use : std::distance   http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance

Just remember to reverse the arguments a-b == std::distance(b,a)

Let me know if this doesn't work.

-----------  amendment -------------

I just tried the example you gave, and realized this isn't the real issue (although you will find distance more portable than iterator arithmetic). The problem is still the debug information, but you need to fix the "char* X = begin(buf)"

Instead use &array[0]

This compiles for me

```
template <size_t N> struct Memchunk 
{
public:
    Memchunk(Memchunk *next_chunk)
        : pos(&buf[0])
        , last(pos)
        , knext(next_chunk)
        , next(nullptr) 
        {
        }

    size_t len() const { return distance(pos,last); }
    size_t left() const { return std::distance(last,buf); }
    void reset() { pos = last = std::begin(buf); }
    std::array<uint8_t, N> buf;
    uint8_t *pos, *last;
    Memchunk *knext;
    Memchunk *next;
    static const size_t size = N;
};
```

(By the way, do you have good reason why your not using std::list? Try this approach below)

```
template <size_t N> struct MemchunkImp 
{
public:
    MemchunkImp()
        : pos(&buf[0])
        , last(pos)
        {
        }

    size_t len() const { return distance(pos,last); }
    size_t left() const { return std::distance(last,buf); }
    void reset() { pos = last = std::begin(buf); }
    std::array<uint8_t, N> buf;
    uint8_t *pos, *last;
    static const size_t size = N;
};

template <size_t N> using Memchunk = std::list<MemchunkImp<N>>;
```