# std::array<int> iterator convertible to int* on clang but not MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang, implicit-conversion

So I have some code like

```
void func( const int* begin, const int* end );
```

and then want to use `std::array<int, X>` to have the data stored, and then call the function like so:

```
std::array<int, 5> data = {1,2,3,4,5};
func( data.begin(), data.end() );
```

When using clang, the iterator apparently is implicitly convertible to `const int*` and everything works as expected.

However on MSVC I'm getting a compiler error

```
C2664 cannot convert argument 1 from `std::_Array_const_iterator<_Ty,5>` to `const int*`
```

Is there a way to coerce the type conversion that I'm somehow missing? Or will I have to do `data.data()[0]` or something lame like that?

Changing the function signature is not really an option

Comment: Iterators are not required to be pointers.

Comment: Something lame like `data.data()` and `data.data() + data.size()`.

Comment: You should be changing `func()` to use `std::span`. That way you aren't limited to containers that allow pointer arithmetic.

Comment: we are not on C++20 yet, otherwise span would be perfect

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44825540/stdbegin-and-stdend-iterators-in-visual-studio

Comment: Probably you could make `func` a template. The `std::array` iterator is required to be a random access operator, i.e. it should allow for the same operations as `const int*` other than conversion.

Comment: @fabian yes agreed would be nice too, but not a great option for the guidelines on this code base

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iterator for `std::array<int>` doesn't necessarily have to be `int*`, it's just `std::array<int>::iterator`, which is up to the individual compiler implementation to decide what it should be.

the standard library provides a function to reliably convert iterators into raw pointers:

`std::addressof(*iterator)`

Although this can also work:

`&(*iterator)`

Comment: "*Although this can also work*" - only for element types that don't override `operator&` (as is true in this case), which is why `std::addressof()` was added to handle those types.